# Steering Wheel Shake New Car Performance Tires

Tags: troubleshooting, chevrolet

I bought a 2012 Camaro 2SS in May. When I took the car for a test drive, the steering wheel had a tight shake for the first couple of miles. When I told the salesperson, he suggested trying another route because it may have been the road. Well, I drove it in a different spot and there was no shake, so I bought the car.

After I bought the car, most mornings the steering wheel would shake for a couple of miles and then stop. This didn't happen every day, but it happened quite a bit. The dealer, and some friends, told me that this can happen with performance tires. They said that the way the settle overnight can cause something inside them to clump together, and driving a few miles will smooth that out. Is that true?

The dealer replaced the front tires and it's still happening. Does it make sense that certain tires would cause this, and I just have to live with a new car where the steering wheel shakes for the first couple of miles? Or is this maybe an indication of something else that's wrong?

I may have to buy winter tires soon, and that may help decide the issue. If the steering wheel no longer shakes with the new tires, then I guess I can assume it was the performance tires all along.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting for a bad rim. The balancer shows everything is A-OK, but the inside is still a different weight than the outside.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to get the dealer to figure out what's up: http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2012/09/my-camaro-issue.html

Comment: You may want to look into the lemon laws in your state [http://www.carlemon.com/](http://www.carlemon.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you gotten the tires re-balanced? When the tires are out of balance, a slight to severe shake on the steering wheel can be felt. Also, control arms or other components that are bent or loose can cause shaking. I would take it to a certified and trusted mechanic (NOT at the dealership) to have a look under the car for any loose nuts and bolts, bent components and check tire balance.

Comment: If those were the issues, would the shaking go away after driving it for a couple of miles?

Comment: @BobHorn If the tires are just slightly out of balance, it could be that when they warm up after driving for a bit they absorb most of the vibration, or if its a loose nut or bolt, the heat absorbed into the nut/bolt from the road and surrounding components makes it expand and tighten...just a thought